# How to eat/serve take no tsuyu (たけの露)?

Tags: soup, dessert, japanese-cuisine

A friend brought me some take no tsuyu (たけの露) from Kyoto.
It looks like this:
[image: tipical Kyoto sweet]

I'm having trouble understanding instructions on how to eat it.

It's served with some hot water, then crushed, then more water is added until it becomes sort of a soup?

Comment: Is that a picture of the container or the food item?  It almost looks like there are seams and those are containers to be opened.  Also, you might want to provide a clear picture of the document in case someone who reads Japanese comes along.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ That is the actual dessert, not an enclosure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place one of the take no tsuyu in a bowl then you pour boiling water over.  The rice cake outer layer will soften and come apart as you stir it with your chopsticks and the red bean soup powder inside will hydrate and create a flavorful broth.